# Вопрос по Jquery Mask Plugin

Tags: jquery

Вопрос следующего порядка - можно ли через регулярку или через три кувырка в данном плагине указать максимальную длину символов в поле ? (maxlength не подходит).
На данный момент костылю так. Нужно max=25, значит спамлю букву AAAAA 25 раз, что является бредятиной

Если кто сталкивался, дайте знать, пожалуйста.

Ссылка на плагин:
https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html

Comment: _maxlength не подходит_ чем он не устраивает? Можно "вручную" ограничить - повесить ивент (keyup какой-то) и считать введённые символы

Comment: @InDevX плагин автоматически меняет maxlength в зависимости от указанных символов.. попробовал после инициализации присвоить атрибуту новое значение - помогло.. на данный момент самый лучший вариант